# CSS Grid: How to Arrange Items in Custom Sequential Left-Right Order?

Tags: css, css-grid

### The situation

I have a list with elements who are already sequentially ordered:

```
<ul>
  <li>1 element</li>
  <li>2 element</li>
  <li>3 element</li>
  <li>4 element</li>
  <li>5 element</li>
  <li>6 element</li>
  <li>7 element</li>
  <li>8 element</li>
  <li>9 element</li>
  <li>10 element</li>
  <li>11 element</li>
</ul>
```

When i use CSS grid and divide the items in two columns, they are automatically ordered left, right, left, right etc.

```
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
```

[image]

### The issue

I want the items to fill the left column first and then the right column. Using CSS grid they should also be equally divided across both columns.
The output should look like this:

[image]

You can test it here: [codepen](https://codepen.io/Jesper/pen/GRzVyrV)
I'm looking for a dynamic solution: The amount of list-elements can be dynamic, so saying "after exactly 6 elements you have to jump to the right column" is not what I'm looking for.

### What I've tried

I tried using `grid-auto-flow: column` but then the items are just placed horizontally:

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue, with only using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in CSS-Grid without specifying the number of rows.

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: max-content;
  column-gap: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1 element</li>
  <li>2 element</li>
  <li>3 element</li>
  <li>4 element</li>
  <li>5 element</li>
  <li>6 element</li>
  <li>7 element</li>
  <li>8 element</li>
  <li>9 element</li>
  <li>10 element</li>
  <li>11 element</li>
</ul>
```

For equally split columns you need to use CSS columns and `column-count`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  column-count: 2;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1 element</li>
  <li>2 element</li>
  <li>3 element</li>
  <li>4 element</li>
  <li>5 element</li>
  <li>6 element</li>
  <li>7 element</li>
  <li>8 element</li>
  <li>9 element</li>
  <li>10 element</li>
  <li>11 element</li>
</ul>
```